# unable to click on Save button while downloading the Excel file using Webdriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to click on Save button while downloading the Excel file using Webdriver in Java as in attached screen shot. I have searched the forum and found the answers but unable to get the results. I am using IE9 browser and my client uses only IE browsers.

[image]

[image]

here is the code for Excel file download:

```
<input name="ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$ImgExcel" title="Export To Excel" id="ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_ImgExcel" style="width: 27px; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px;" type="image" src="Common/images/icons_02.gif" border="0"/>
```

Can anyone please help me to download the Excel file using Webdriver in Java. In the screenshot i have removed the actual URL.

This requirement in IE browser.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: The button you want to want to click on is not a HTML element, `webdriver` will not be able to interact with it. You'll need to use something like the `Robot` class to force a click at that location. Understand that downloading files is really not what Webdriver was designed for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark. I know that Webdriver is not designed for downloading files. But we can achieve it by workaround.

Comment: public static void clickAndSaveFileIE(WebElement element) throws InterruptedException{
try{Robot robot = new Robot();
element.sendKeys("");
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
//wait for the modal dialog to open            
Thread.sleep(2000);
//press s key to save            
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
Thread.sleep(2000);
//press enter to save the file with default name and in default location
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
catch (AWTException e) 
{e.printStackTrace();}
}

Comment: Read and never forget this article: 
http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Comment: Please find the code added for the Excel file download

Answer (score 0):

yeah i have faced same situation.
use Robot class &key events

For IE to save a file click ALT+S
to open ALT+O

so

```
    Robot robot=new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
```

and your file will be downloaded

-Ajay

Answer (score 0):

You can also use AutoIT for such actions. See [here](http://www.mythoughts.co.in/2013/11/download-file-using-selenium-webdriver.html) for a good article on how to use AutoIT to download files.